# Turn Monitor Back On after xrandr

Tags: hdmi, xrandr

I keep my Laptop PC always connected to my HDMI tv. When I am watching a movie on the tv, i use the command `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off` to turn my laptop screen Off (it is annoying to see the movie on a small screen beside the Tv).
So, with this command, the Laptop Screen is Off, and everything is displayed in the TV

The question is: How do i Turn my Laptop Screen BACK ON? Right now, i have to remove the HDMI cable, then it turns on. I Would like to do it via Command Line. How?????

Answer (score 13):

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto
```

did it

Answer (score 9):

When accidentally disabling the only attached display, trying to reenable it from another virtual console will yield in the following error message:

> xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

Please make sure the actual virtual console where X Windows is running is active, when xrandr is actuating the configuration. Typing the following in the first virtual console rescued me:

> sudo chvt 7; sleep 3; xrandr --display :0.0 --auto

Comment: chvt life saver

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --right-of HDMI-1 --auto
```

enables `LVDS-1`, putting it logically beyond right side of `HDMI-1`. The other two answers here copies the current display in both screens.